# PHP mail do not wait

Tags: php, email

I'm sending a plain text mail with php's mail() function using local postfix. Unfortunately the mail shipment takes between 2-4 seconds and this is too long to wait. Is there a way to tell the php() function to not wait for a response of postfix? How can I achieve this?

Comment: if that's to long, then email is not the answer, it can take hours for an email to get delivered

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do it in your current script. Some things take some time.

If you want to improve that, you have to setup a queue system that quickly accepts the task to send a mail, and then does it asynchronously at a later point in time. Do a search for "Gearman" and alternatives.